# How do I load and excel addins in vb.net?

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-addins

I have to create an excel file in VB.NET to make some calculations trough a excel add-in (if you are asking, no, recreating the add-in inside the program itself is not an option), I have done some research and according to the microsoft.docs website I would have to use my application variable (aka appXl) and write `appXl.AddIns.Add([filename])`, but it fails every time, again according to the microsoft.docs I should open the workbook.

I tried using `appXl.AddIns2.Add([filename])`, but it failed too, I tried various solutions found on the internet, but none seem to work, I also tried using the title, or the directory, but it doesn't work

code:
vb.net

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Private appXl As Excel.Application
Private wbXl As Excel.Workbook
Private shXl As Excel.Worksheet
Private AddinXl As Excel.AddIn
Private dataDirectory As String = (String.Format("{0}\Data\", Environment.CurrentDirectory))

Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  dataDirectory &= "AnimalFeed.xlsx"
  appXl = New Excel.Application
  wbXl = appXl.Workbooks.Open(dataDirectory)
  shXl = wbXl.Worksheets("solver")
  AddinXl = appXl.AddIns.Add("wba.xlam")
End Sub
```

it should load the plugin and then be able to use all of its functions inside vb.net, but the debug stops to the `AddinXl = appXl.AddIns.Add("wba.xlam")` line and it just says *"Add method of AddIns class failed"*.

Comment: Maybe you should specify full path for add-in?

Comment: Already tried, doesn't work

Comment: Is "wba.xlam" a _known_ Excel Addin?  i.e. it is listed in Excel's Adin-In dialog box?

Comment: if you mean that if i open it from excel in options > Add-ins it works, yes, I also tried using the title instead of the file name, but I had no luck

Comment: I meant is it currently listed in the dialog (without you having to add it).  The listed add-ins need special handling ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712160/2592875).  You should be passing the full path to the `Addins.Add` method.  Once you finally get it to load, you also have to set the `AddIn.Installed` property to `True`.

Comment: ok, now I see what you meant, no, it is not an xl known addin, I had to add it in the dialog box, the  problem is that I don't have an xll file for this addin

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Excel in your references?

I'm sorry I can't guide you through this as I haven't used VB.net in ages, but in order to use the Excel objects, you'll need the reference.

You'll know if you have added it when type `Excel`, the list of possible options will appear.

If not, look for `Tools -> References` and find Excel probably under Microsoft first. Google vb.net with your version numbers (.Net and Excel) to get an exact guide.

Comment: yes, I did add it, otherwise the program would stop at the first line, in fact this program is just a modification of another already working program, I just needed to add the addin part, thanks anyway